# Wrong number or TYPES of arguments, error in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, record, plsqldeveloper

I have to create a list of RECORD and I need to send it to a procedure.

There is my header.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tema4 IS
 TYPE obj IS RECORD(id INTEGER := 0,percent INTEGER := 0);
 TYPE listObj IS TABLE OF obj INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 PROCEDURE ex1 (p_listObj IN listObj);
END tema4;
```

My body.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY tema4 IS
PROCEDURE ex1 (p_listObj IN listObj) IS
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant reach');
END ex1;
END tema4;
```

And my code that calls procedure ex1.

```
DECLARE
 TYPE obj IS RECORD(id INTEGER := 0,percent INTEGER := 0);
 TYPE listObj IS TABLE OF obj INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 v_obj obj;
 v_listObj listObj;
BEGIN
 FOR v_i IN (SELECT ID,BURSA FROM STUDENTI ORDER BY ID) LOOP
  v_obj.id := v_i.id;
  v_obj.percent := 50;
  v_listObj(v_i.id) := v_obj;
 END LOOP;
 FOR v_i IN v_listObj.FIRST..v_listObj.LAST LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_listObj(v_i).id || ' - ' || 
  v_listObj(v_i).percent);
 END LOOP;
 tema4.ex1(v_listObj); --this line is with problems
END;
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EX1'

Can someone explain me what is wrong in my code? I also tried to create my type as global, but it won't let me because of 'RECORD' keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare the types again (new types), use the types already declared in the package spec:

```
DECLARE
 v_obj tema4.obj;
 v_listObj tema4.listObj;
BEGIN
 FOR v_i IN (SELECT ID,BURSA FROM STUDENTI ORDER BY ID) LOOP
  v_obj.id := v_i.id;
  v_obj.percent := 50;
  v_listObj(v_i.id) := v_obj;
 END LOOP;
 FOR v_i IN v_listObj.FIRST..v_listObj.LAST LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_listObj(v_i).id || ' - ' || 
  v_listObj(v_i).percent);
 END LOOP;
 tema4.ex1(v_listObj); --this line is with problems
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's working.
I lost some good hours with that simple thing.